# numpy installation error on win10_x64(UnicodeEncodeError)

Tags: python, numpy, unicode

I tried to install numpy on a win10 (language was set to be Russian) with pip(8.0.2).first it was error because of there was no c++ compiler,I handled it.However latter it says that there are an UnicodeEncodeError reported like this:

```
File "c:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-14: ordinal not in range(128)

Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\7272~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-tqxxjr\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
```

Comment: The easiest method of installing numpy on Windows is to download a wheel from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and install it with `pip`.